# python - connecting to a database with pyodbc - not working

Tags: python, database, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to an Access 2007 database with the following connection string.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=<C:\Users\JSeinfeld\Desktop\Backup databases\Database_6.7.accdb>;")
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={Microsoft
>   Access Driver (*.mdb,
>   *.accdb)};DBQ=;")
>
> Error: ('HY000', "[HY000]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access
>   Driver]General error Unable to open
>   registry key Temporary (volatile) Ace
>   DSN for process 0x167c Thread 0x1568
>   DBC 0x1c67a5c
>
> Jet'. (63) (SQLDriverConnectW);
>   [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft
>   Access Driver]General error Unable to
>   open registry key Temporary (volatile)
>   Ace DSN for process 0x167c Thread
>   0x1568 DBC 0x1c67a5c
>
> Jet'. (63); [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Microsoft Access Driver] Not a valid
>   file name. (-1044); [HY000]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access
>   Driver]General error Unable to open
>   registry key Temporary (volatile) Ace
>   DSN for process 0x167c Thread 0x1568
>   DBC 0x1c67a5c
>
> Jet'. (63); [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Microsoft Access Driver]General error
>   Unable to open registry key Temporary
>   (volatile) Ace DSN for process 0x167c
>   Thread 0x1568 DBC 0x1c67a5c
>
> Jet'. (63); [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Microsoft Access Driver] Not a valid
>   file name. (-1044)")

There is another question like this on SO, but there was a 32/64bit compatibility issue which I do not have. There doesn't seem to be a good answer for this question, but hopefully someone can help me connect to my database because I don't know of any other way to query or write data to Access 2007 with python.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue - it was a simple case of escaping the backslash used in the location of the access db

`>>> conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\access\\site_be.accdb;")`

worked as whereas

`>>> conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\access\site_be.accdb;")`

was giving me the error 
`Jet'. (63); [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Not a valid file name. (-1044)")`

Hope that helped..

Answer (score 2):

Try taking the brackets out of the file name.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\JSeinfeld\Desktop\Backup databases\Database_6.7.accdb")
```

Comment: hey Stephen, I can't test this until Monday but I hope it's that simple :) +1 though, it makes perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an *.ldb file in your folder?

I had very similar error messages, but mine also included "file already in use."  In my case, I finally realized that there was a lock on the database (an .ldb file next to the .mdb).  I have a service running that uses the database all the time -- I guess it's time to switch to a multi-user database engine.

As an experiment, I made a copy of the database, and pyodbc connected to the copy just fine.  This obviously isn't a long-term solution, but at least now I know what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Fabiolus got it right.

The  backslash character means that the next character has special meaning in a string.  So deciphering the double backslash...  The first backslash tells python to prepare for a special string character, the second backslash is the special string character (which in this case is a backslash)

```
\n = newline
\t = tab
\\ = backslash
```