# Pyodbc Error - Python to MS Access

Tags: python, ms-access, odbc, pyodbc

I am running on Windows 7, Python 2.7 and Microsoft Access 2013.

When I try running:

```
import pyodbc
conn_string = '''
DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};
UID=admin;
UserCommitSync=Yes;
Threads=3;
SafeTransactions=0;
PageTimeout=5;
MaxScanRows=8;
MaxBufferSize=2048;
FIL=MS Access;
DriverId=25;
DefaultDir=C:\Users\jseinfeld;
DBQ=C:\Users\jseinfeld\Desktop\Databasetest1.accdb;
'''
connection = pyodbc.connect(conn_string)
```

I receive the following error message:

```
Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process 0x29dc Thread 0x113c DBC 0x8a3ed48    

Jet'. (63) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process 0x29dc Thread 0x113c DBC 0x8a3ed48

Jet'. (63); [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Not a valid file name. (-1044); [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process 0x29dc Thread 0x113c DBC 0x8a3ed48 

Jet'. (63); [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process 0x29dc Thread 0x113c DBC 0x8a3ed48

Jet'. (63); [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Not a valid file name. (-1044)")
```

I realize there are many questions regarding Pyodbc and MS Access. I have already executed the following:

1) Ensured I have 64 bit Python and 64 bit MS Access

2) Given permission to the account access to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC registry key

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/295297

[Error in opening an Access database in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473737/error-in-opening-an-access-database-in-python)

["General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) ..." from Access ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244425/general-error-unable-to-open-registry-key-temporary-volatile-from-access/26317631#26317631)

3) Tried to ensure I have a valid connection string [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469545/python-connecting-to-a-database-with-pyodbc-not-working#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469545/python-connecting-to-a-database-with-pyodbc-not-working#_=_)

4) The Access database is not open when I try running this code. I have re-booted my computer and am still receiving this error.

Please let me know if there is any other action I can try.

Comment: The way you build the connection string means that it includes embedded line breaks.  Have you tried it without line breaks?  ... starting from a raw string something like this: `conn_string = r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\jseinfeld\Desktop\Databasetest1.accdb;'`

Comment: good call-out but yes I have tried exactly that

Comment: Those "Not a valid file name." entries suggest that it might be a typo in the file path or perhaps a permissions issue. Have you tried copying the file to someplace like "C:\Users\Public\..." (and double-checking the file name)?

Comment: Also, I've never seen `Threads=` in an Access connection string.  Suggest you combine Gord's suggestion with a simplified connection string ... starting with just the `Driver` and `DBQ` properties.

Comment: @GordThompson I am assured the file path name is correct. I put the database on my desktop. I agree that there might be a permissions issue because this is not a personal computer. But I do not know how to check for that. I have followed a previous answer of yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473737/error-in-opening-an-access-database-in-python

Comment: @HansUp I have tried many different connection strings including the one from your comment: `conn_string = r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\jseinfeld\Desktop\Databasetest1.accdb;`

Comment: @HansUp I take back my last comment. I have tried `conn_string = 'rDRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\jseinfeld\Desktop\Databasetest1.accdb;'` 
but not 
`conn_string = r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\jseinfeld\Desktop\Databasetest1.accdb;'`
Your first comment here solved my issue. Can you post it as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with a simple connection string with only the `DRIVER` and `DBQ` attributes and no embedded line breaks ...

```
conn_string = r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\jseinfeld\Desktop\Databasetest1.accdb;'
```

Once you get the simplest connection string working, you can add and test other connection attributes as needed.

Answer (score 4):

Additional to HansUp's answer, I use the following technique to build connection strings without embedded line breaks that are still easy to read by us humans:

```python
conn_string = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=C:\Users\jseinfeld\Desktop\Databasetest1.accdb;')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use just *.mdb you can build the connection like this: to avoid the error ODBC Driver not found.

```
db_main = f"C:\Users\jseinfeld\Desktop\Databasetest1.mdb"

conn_string = r"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};" \
   f"DBQ={db_main}"
```

Comment: Note that this will only work for apps running under 32-bit Python (on Windows).